# Set Route Path With Query Params without navigating to the route, directly in the routing module

Tags: angular, typescript

there will be a link in email, when that link is clicked, i want to open List component.

the url of that link will be like :

> http://localhost:4200/list?Key=SdmfbjaBJHKbbjbv47g+ffh/fbf

*Key=**SdmfbjaBJHKbbjbv47g+ffh/fbf***

in this link there can be any kind of value in Key, i just need to get that value as it is while opening the list component which has a form, then i can send the form value and the key.

i want to set the path in the route array in the routing module but that only works for:

> http://localhost:4200/list/SdmfbjaBJHKbbjbv47g+ffh/fbf

```
{path:'list:key', component:ListComponent},
```

i was trying for:

> http://localhost:4200/list?Key=SdmfbjaBJHKbbjbv47g+ffh/fbf

```
{path:'list?Key=:key', component:ListComponent},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly specify query parameters in the route path. Query parameters are used to pass additional information to a route, but they are not part of the route itself.

Modify your route configuration to remove the query parameter from the path

```
{ path: 'list', component: ListComponent }
```

In your ListComponent, import the necessary modules

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      const key = params['Key'];
      // Use the 'key' value as needed in your component
    });
  }
}
```

When the link is clicked, Angular will navigate to the ListComponent, and the ngOnInit method will be called. Inside that method, the queryParams observable is subscribed to, allowing you to extract the Key value from the URL

hope it's helpful..

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to declare query parameters in the routes array.

Routes:

`{path:'list', component:ListComponent},`

ListComponent (example):

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

...some code...

this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => params['key'])

or

this.route.snapshot.queryParams['key']
```